Why am I getting an HTTP error 404 with pywikigraph?
I'm trying to make code that finds the shortest possible path between two Wikipedia articles. When I run it, the following error is returned:
Downloading index.pkl... (may take several minutes as it is 1 GB)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\thomp\wikispeedrunning.py", line 6, in <module>
    wikirace = WikiGraph().get_shortest_paths_info(startpoint, endpoint)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\thomp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pywikigraph\wikigraph.py", line 211, in get_shortest_paths_info
    if not self._exists(topic=source, verbose=verbose):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\thomp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pywikigraph\wikigraph.py", line 164, in _exists
    if topic not in self.topic_index_map:
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\thomp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pywikigraph\wikigraph.py", line 111, in topic_index_map
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 240, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 215, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 521, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 630, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 559, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 492, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 639, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Here is my code:
from pywikigraph import WikiGraph

wikispeedrun = WikiGraph()

startpoint = input('Enter the starting article:')
endpoint = input('Enter the article to navigate to:')

wikirace = wikispeedrun.get_shortest_paths_info(startpoint, endpoint)
print(wikirace)

My code is basically a copy of "How to use the package" on the PyPI page, with the only code changed being the input functions.
I am unsure as to why this happens and was unable to find any other examples of the same or similar errors, partially because there are so many questions with 'python' and '404' that I don't know where to look.
I tried getting rid of the input functions and just completely copying the code on the PyPI page, which would look like this:
from pywikigraph import WikiGraph
wg = WikiGraph()
paths = wg.get_shortest_paths_info('Backpropagation', 'Data Science')
print(paths)

but that still returned the same error.
